# Formatting/printing execve arguments

Tags: macos, dtrace

I'm trying to print out the environment from an execve call. I'm capturing this via:

```
syscall::exec*:entry {
  printf("%i %i %s %s\n", ppid, pid, execname, copyinstr(arg0));
}
```

But I can't seem to convince dtrace that `arg2[0]` is something that could be printed. How do I get the `envp` contents in this case?

Comment: It's a bit hard to print a value such as `arg2[0]` that never appears in your code.  How are you trying to print `arg2[0]`?

Comment: It's just an example of what I would expect to be possible. I want to print the environment from the `execve` call. You can ignore the `arg2[0]` bit if you find it confusing.

Comment: Before or after the actual `exec()` call replaces the process?

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible using **curpsinfo** built-in variable, its **pr_envp** [field](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5174/proc-4.html#REFMAN4proc-4). But it wouldn't be easy since it's array and dtrace doesn't support loops. Probably you can hack it by using famous [newproc.d](https://opensource.apple.com/source/dtrace/dtrace-168/DTTk/Proc/newproc.d.auto.html) script and replacing there *curpsinfo->pr_argv* with *curpsinfo->pr_envp* but you should do something with count as well, i.e. this->argc - maybe set it to some high value? Anyway, check replies and discussion for [this question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/201896/how-do-i-find-what-processes-with-args-are-being-run-on-os-x-leopard-during). I think the same applies to environment variables.